# Read version constant by qmake in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have seen where people will define variables like `VERSION` using a `config.h` header with autotools that are constants in C or C++, so that their version numbers are accurate. Is there a way to do this in qmake?

I added a line like

```ini
VERSION = 6.3.a
```

to my `project.pro` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@AlexHenrie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28008258/3755692) is correct but qmake prefers this settings in the `DEFINES` variable, like this:

```
DEFINES += VERSION=$$VERSION
```

For more information, see http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html#defines

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest way is to define it at compile time like this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DVERSION=$$VERSION
```

You will then be able to access VERSION from any .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can make qmake generate a config.h file like this:

```
system(echo \\$${LITERAL_HASH}define VERSION $$VERSION > config.h)
```